# How to do this with dplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this dummy dataset that I am trying to de-aggregate. Meaning that the 2 age records will need to be broken down on to 8 rows based on age 5 plus age 3.I can do this with Base R but I would like to do the same with dplyr to keep all of my code consistent. Thanks for any help.

```
a <- data.frame(name= c("Maria", "Tina"), age= c(5,3)) ;a
    name age
1 Maria   5
2  Tina   3

#Break down age based on its value. First row will create 5 rows and second row will create 3 more #rows for a total of 8 rows.

 aa <- a[rep(1:nrow(a),a$age),]
 aa
 aa$rows  <- rep(1:nrow(a),a$age)
 aa

#Final product
     name age rows
1   Maria   5    1
1.1 Maria   5    1
1.2 Maria   5    1
1.3 Maria   5    1
1.4 Maria   5    1
2    Tina   3    2
2.1  Tina   3    2
2.2  Tina   3    2

#How can I do the above with dplyr?
```

Comment: `a %>% mutate(rows = row_number()) %>% uncount(age, .remove = FALSE)` this uses libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Comment: Great, thak you @RonakShah It works like a charm now.